# C++ how to #define/rename a nested function?

Tags: c++, macros

```
    namespace first {
    namespace second {
        class Third {
            static void foo() {
                std::cout << "foo\n";
            }
        };
    }
    }

    void bar() {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }

    #define first::second::Third::foo bar//this doesn't work
```

so, what's the correct way to map a nested function to another one?

## Update:

a more similar situation is:

```
    struct ReleaseVersion {
        static void foo() {
            std::cout << "release version\n";
        }
    };

    struct DebugVersion {
        static void foo() {
            std::cout << "debug version\n";
        }
    };

    #ifdef _DEBUG 
    #define ReleaseVersion::foo DebugVersion::foo
    #else
    #define DebugVersion::foo ReleaseVersion::foo
    #endif
```

what I want to do is just like malloc and _malloc_dbg, when #define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC, in debug mode, malloc will be mapped to _malloc_dbg, and in release mode, _malloc_dbg will be mapped to malloc

## Update again

a more more similar situation is:

```
    namespace first {
    namespace second {
    struct ReleaseVersion {
        static void foo() {
            std::cout << "release version\n";
        }
    };
    
    struct DebugVersion {
        static void foo(const char* file, long line) {
            std::cout << "debug version\n";
        }
    };
    }
    }
    #ifdef _DEBUG 
    #define ReleaseVersion::foo() DebugVersion::foo(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    #else
    #define DebugVersion::foo(file, line) ReleaseVersion::foo()
    #endif
```

so, these 2 version of functions may have different parameters, I cannot just call one.
I know I can just do this

```
    #ifdef _DEBUG 
    #define Foo() first::second::DebugVersion::foo(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    #else
    #define Foo() first::second::ReleaseVersion::foo()
```

but in this way, I must always use Foo(), even in the final release mode, it's still a macro.
I want to know if there are more flexible way to to do this.

## One Solution

```
    #ifdef _DEBUG 
    #define foo() foo(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define ReleaseVersion DebugVersion
    #else
    #define foo(file, line) foo()
    #define DebugVersion ReleaseVersion
    #endif
    
    
    int main() {
        first::second::DebugVersion::foo(__FILE__, __LINE__);
        first::second::ReleaseVersion::foo();
        return 0;
    }
```

it may be dangerous when there are another foo() or RealeaseVersion/DebugVersion in other namespaces,
but if you can make sure there won't, I think it can be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You have two different definitions, but you want to give them a single name?? Why?

Comment: Use an editor and change the name.

Comment: The preprocessor only allows proper identifier names, i.e. it has to start with a letter, and only contain letters, digits and underscore.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I wrote some static methods inside a class, I want to map these static functions to the correct version according to a macro,such as _DEBUG.

Comment: @Mankarse ,one is debug version, just like malloc and _malloc_dbg, these 2 function names are both always mapped to the correct version.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , it's true, so I wonder is there any other ways to make it work.

Comment: Explain better what you **really** want to achieve. Seems that you are confusing some concepts...

Comment: @MatheusOl ,I want to make both the 2 lines of code works identically in either debug or release mode first::second::DebugVersion::foo_dbg(__FILE__, __LINE__);
 first::second::ReleaseVersion::foo();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#define` is the wrong way around:

```
#define bar first::second::Third::foo
```

means that `bar` will be replaced by `first::second::Third::foo`, which, I believe, is what you want.

This is the opposite of `typedef`, where things are the other way around.

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but this works:

```
namespace first {
namespace second {
    class Third {
        public: static void foo() {
            std::cout << "foo\n";
        }
    };
}
}

#define bar first::second::Third::foo

int main()
{
  bar();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for my situation, I have updated my question.

Comment: @Frahm Ok, but can't you just call `bar()` everywhere where you want to call the function, or just `#define` "ReleaseVersion" to "DebugVersion" (without the `::`)?

Comment: this is the simplified example, in my real situation, there are 2 more namespace ouside the class

Answer (score 1):

The way `malloc`/`free` works is by a macro replacement:

```
#ifdef WANT_DEBUG_MALLOC
#define malloc(x) debug_malloc(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define free(x)   debug_free(x, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#endif
```

When the preprocessor sees `struct foo *p = malloc(sizeof(struct foo) * 10);` it will replace it with `struct foo *p = debug_malloc(sizeof(struct foo) * 10, "myfile.c", 103);`

However, as mentioned above, you can't really use namespaces when doing the macro replacement. You have to EITHER replace the namespace alone, or replace the function name alone. Of course, it's possible to have two macros, one to substitute the namespace, and one for substituting the function name. But it gets pretty messy pretty quickly, so best avoided, I'd say.

Comment: "You have to EITHER replace the namespace alone, or replace the function name"Thanks, I got the solution

Answer (score 0):

I would rather using inline functions

```
#ifdef _DEBUG 
static inline void DoFoo() { DebugVersion::foo(); }
#else
static inline void DoFoo() { ReleaseVersion::foo(); }
#endif
```

Comment: but the parameters may be different

Comment: How about define debug version like this: `static inline void DoFoo__(const char * file, int line) { DebugVersion::foo(file,line); }  #define DoFoo() DoFoo__(__FILE__,__LINE__)` ?

Comment: I think it's the same as: #define DoFoo() DebugVersion::foo(__FILE__,__LINE__)